# Why does the JIRA User for the Rally Jira Connector have to be a JIRA Administrator?

Tags: jira, rally

I've been asked to look at configuring the [Rally JIRA Connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/plugin.jral) to synchronise Rally with our JIRA instance and the [installation instructions](http://www.rallydev.com/help/jira-installation-user-guide) state that the user you create in JIRA has to be a JIRA Administrator. Why does it need admin permissions when all it appears to be doing is updating the RallyID and RallyURL custom fields for issues in the JIRA project(s) synching with Rally.

Are edit permissions for issues on the project not enough, or is it doing something else that requires admin privileges? I did remove the user from the jira-administrators group, but the connector checks for administrator privileges and halts if the user is not an admin.

If the user does not need admin privileges is it possible to alter/remove the check in the connector so that the user can be removed from the jira-administrators group and just be given the relevant permissions in JIRA?

Thanks,

Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a 2 part answer:

1. The connector runs a validation step on your config file to verify that all of the fields you have mapped do exist in Jira.  Historically, with earlier versions of Jira out of the box, only the administrators group had permissions to get that list of fields on issues.
2. If you are using a field handler to transform in users to Jira, we again needed higher level permissions to get the list of users in Jira - eg to do a lookup based on email.

Hope that information helps.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I guess there's no way of running it with lower permissions then?

Comment: Not sure if this what is going on, but the JIRA SOAP API requires the user is a JIRA administrator to get the list of custom fields in JIRA

Comment: Correct - per what mdoar added - the connector does currently use the JIRA SOAP API - we're looking to move it to REST in the future, but still have a few others out there on earlier versions of Jira 4 that we support.